# Hibernate Annotation Exception when migrating from JBoss 5.1 to JBoss EAP 6

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa, jboss, persistence

My understanding is that JBoss 5.1 uses Hibernate 3.4.0.GA. JBoss 6 uses Hibernate 4.2.18.Final.

I have an entity class with a @ManyToOne,@JoinTable reference which seems to run fine in JBoss 5.1. Please see the simplified class below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "[Professional Activity (Field Display Names)]")
public class ProfessionalActivity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(name = "[Professional Activity User Relationship]", 
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "[Professional Activity ID]"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "[User ID]"))
    private User user;

}
```

Needless to say (but I'll say it anyway!), [Professional Activity User Relationship] is just a "Join Table" that maps Professional Activities to Users. Again, this is working great with old Hibernate. Is this a bug in Hibernate 4 or is there a better way to be annotating this? This is the stack trace I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: efcEntityManagerLocal] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:925)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:900)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:59)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
    at edu.emory.first.cache.service.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:15)
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Cannot find the expected secondary table: no Professional Activity User Relationship available for edu.emory.first.cache.model.ProfessionalActivity
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column.getJoin(Ejb3Column.java:372)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column.getTable(Ejb3Column.java:351)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindManyToOne(AnnotationBinder.java:2741)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1728)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:895)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:728)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3625)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3579)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1381)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1786)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
    ... 5 more
```

**Update**

It looks like it might be related to the fact that my backing DB is a SQLServer Database and the table I'm trying to join is required to have either brackets, back-ticks, or quotes (when I escape them with a backslash).

Basically, these three make the SQL happy but not Hibernate:

```
name = "\"Professional Activity User Relationship\""
name = "`Professional Activity User Relationship`"
name = "[Professional Activity User Relationship]"
```

I've tried changing the Dialects from Sql2008Server, Sql2012Server, etc. to no avail. I've tried NO specified dialect in the persistence.xml and that didn't seem to change anything.

Basically I see two workarounds, although I'd rather not do either.

1. Create a view of the offending table and make the name with no spaces so I don't have to use the characters([,`,\") which seem to be causing the issue (i.e. Professional_Activity_User_Relationship_View).
2. Create an entity class for the join table, add a few ManyToOne Relationships and just increase my joins at the EntityManager query level.

Neither are optimal. Is this an issue I should raise with Hibernate? Seems like even switching to 5 didn't resolve the issue.

**Update 2**

I have created a JIRA ticket for this: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10660